# Python package not available in PyCharm package installer

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pypi

I created a python package named ***exploitsearch*** which is available on PyPi.
[image: 1]

But when I try to install the same in PyCharm using repo installer, its not visible.
[image: 2]

PS: Repository is pointed correctly.
[image: 3]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPI admin here. It may take up to 24 hours for new projects to be included at `pypi.org/simple`.